# How to Compare 2 values in 1 table corresponding to date and create another column in dyanmo db

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose we have 2 rows with date and I have to compare amount with previous date and put that value in another row in dynamo db. How can I do this?

```
TimePeriod LinkedAccount Amount       Estimated  Unit
 2018-07-04 711035872*** 0.7715992257 True       USD
 2018-07-05 7110358***** 0.7715549731 True       USD
```

Comment: Did you check how to put data in Dynamo DB?. Check `boto3` lib.

Comment: yes already did

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. There is no ability to write queries that compare one row with another row.

Instead, your application should retrieve all relevant rows and them make the comparison.

Or, retrieve one row, figure out the desired values, then call DynamoDB again with parameters to retrieve any matching row (eg for the previous date).